# Fire event from hyperlink in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How would I fire an event (I am wanting to switch card views) from a plain old html link?

If I reference the link by ID in my controls section no event I tried (click, tap) seems to be triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: share you code please

Answer (score 2):

Once you render the link you can add event listener in this way:

```
Ext.get('[link id here]').on('click', function(){...}, this);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to fire an event once user clicked on hyperlink, you can simply add `this.fireEvent('[name of event here]');` but be aware of `this` keyword meaning in this function, so you'll have an ability to add listener to it properly... Does it make sense?

Comment: he asks how to fire the event not to listen for

Comment: Hmm.. So I need to switch cards using a hyperlink. Yes I can make a random listener to popup an alert box or something but using Ext.get... inside my controller's init does not seem to give me access to switching views in the same way that the control() function does. I am trying to trigger this to happen: `main = this.getIntroView();main.setActiveItem({xtype: intro});`

Comment: Could you post more code, so it will be easier to understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok so I have a container called main which is a card layout. One of the cards has an xtype of 'intro'. I would like, from another card which contains a plain html link to slide to the intro card.

My current code which works fine for a button that does the same things is:

    init: function() {
          this.control({
            'mybutton': {
                tap: function(btn) {
                    main = this.getMain();
                    main.setActiveItem({
                       xtype: 'intro'
                 });

So I would like my href to achieve the same kind of thing.

Comment: You need to use `Ext.get` when your link is rendered already. i.e. do event subscription not in `init`, but in `onRender` or subscribe to 'afterrender' event in main.

Comment: onRender doesn't have access to the link. afterrender is gone - it's been replaced by 'painted' - haven't yet figured out how to make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click listener to the panel containing the link. In the example the  tag has the 'link' class. You can substitute it by your own class/id, as it's done in jQuery.

```
listeners: {
    scope: this,
    itemtap: this.onItemtapAction,
    click: {
       element: 'el',
       fn: function (e) {
          if (e.getTarget('a.link')) {
              // Switch cards here
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used simple Java Script to add a listener to the link.

First, I created an "activate" listener for the container component:

```
 ...
 listeners: {
        activate: function (newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
            this.onActivate(newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts);
        }
    }
...
```

And here is my function:

```
onActivate: function (newActiveItem, mainNavView, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
        var me = this;

        document.getElementById('logOutLink').addEventListener("click",
           function(){
               me.onLogOut();
           }, false);
       },
onLogOut:function(){
        alert('log out');
    }
```